# Type mismatch after copy/pasting to multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a small Excel macro that auto executes upon cell update:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Value = "N/A" Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(205, 201, 201)
    End If

    If Target.Value = "Pass" Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

    If Target.Value = "Fail" Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

However, when I try to copy and paste any cell(s) across multiple other cells, I get this error:

Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: This task would be better accomplished using `Conditional Formatting`

Comment: although the answer below should work, Conditional Formatting  would be a far better approach! [Conditional Formatting on Contextures.com](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html)

Comment: ... probably but not absolutely Philip. It depends on the actual scope of the question, Excel version etc.

Answer (score 4):

Because in this case you have more than one cell in `Target`. Try this code

*I have disabled `Events` as it is good practice when working with `Worksheet_Change` - even though cell color changes won't re-trigger events*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

For Each rng1 In Target.Cells
   Select Case rng1.Value
   Case "N/A"
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(205, 201, 201)
   Case "Pass"
      Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
       Case "Fail"
      Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End Select
Next

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```